# How to deploy BTC blockchain on my Ubuntu17 VPS

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, crypto-2.0

I would like to setup Bitcoin nodes on my VPS so we can call balance API unlimited time. Actually we are launching ICO for that we are in need of this we have previously deployed ETH and NEO node on our VPS.

Can any share URL or document that can help me to deploy bitcoin Nodes on my VPS and it allows to RPC Call for getting balance of any address.

Comment: maybe this (using Bitcoin Core) - even though it is for Ubuntu 16:  https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#ubuntu-1604

Comment: Thanks you, i have started deployment of BTC as per your url, Now i am struct at one point can you guide me. I have started bitcoin node using " bitcoind -daemon" but after 5 to 10 mins when i try to run bitcoin-cli command what we have to pass in parameter ? @pebwindkraft

Comment: Did you install full QT client, or daemon only? I assume you have had no errors after/during install (check log files?). Then the next step might be to prepare the bitcoin.conf file, in the home directory of the user running your bitcoin daemon (and this is not ‚root‘). You might need to set the user and password in this file. Hint: there is plenty of info here in the forum, just search for bitcoin.conf.